# Jackson deserialization/serialization does not sort properties

Tags: java, sorting, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm using **Jackson 2.8.9** in my application to generate some JSON. I have some unit tests in which I compare generated JSON with some files content.

When I compare my generated JSON with my file content, it does not match due to the properties order.

For the tests to be repeatable I need to have the properties sorted alphabetically. But with Jackson, it does not seems to work.

I wrote some tests for illustation. Only `should_indent_properties` pass.

```
public class FormatJsonWithJacksonTest {

private static final String INDENTED_UNSORTED = "{\r\n" + 
        "  \"firstChild\" : {\r\n" + 
        "    \"subChild\" : {\r\n" + 
        "      \"alphaItem\" : \"1234567891234567\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"otherProperty\" : \"2017-06-21\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"someOtherProperty\" : \"NONE\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"alphaType\" : \"KIND_OF_TYPE\"\r\n" + 
        "    }\r\n" + 
        "  }\r\n" + 
        "}";

private static final String INDENTED_SORTED = "{\r\n" + 
        "  \"firstChild\" : {\r\n" + 
        "    \"subChild\" : {\r\n" + 
        "      \"alphaItem\" : \"1234567891234567\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"alphaType\" : \"KIND_OF_TYPE\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"otherProperty\" : \"2017-06-21\",\r\n" + 
        "      \"someOtherProperty\" : \"NONE\"\r\n" + 
        "    }\r\n" + 
        "  }\r\n" + 
        "}";

private static final String UNINDENTED_UNSORTED = "{" + 
        "\"firstChild\":{" + 
        "\"subChild\":{" + 
        "\"alphaItem\":\"1234567891234567\"," + 
        "\"otherProperty\":\"2017-06-21\"," + 
        "\"someOtherProperty\":\"NONE\"," + 
        "\"alphaType\":\"KIND_OF_TYPE\"" + 
        "}" + 
        "}" + 
        "}";

private static final String UNINDENTED_SORTED = "{" + 
        "\"firstChild\":{" + 
        "\"subChild\":{" + 
        "\"alphaItem\":\"1234567891234567\"," + 
        "\"alphaType\":\"KIND_OF_TYPE\"," + 
        "\"otherProperty\":\"2017-06-21\"," + 
        "\"someOtherProperty\":\"NONE\"" + 
        "}" + 
        "}" + 
        "}";

@Test
public void should_sort_properties() throws Exception {
    // Given
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper = objectMapper
            .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);

    // When
    String formattedJson = tryingToFormatJson(objectMapper, INDENTED_UNSORTED);

    // Then
    assertEquals(UNINDENTED_SORTED, formattedJson);
}


@Test
public void should_indent_properties() throws Exception {
    // Given
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper = objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    // When
    String formattedJson = tryingToFormatJson(objectMapper, UNINDENTED_UNSORTED);

    // Then
    assertEquals(INDENTED_UNSORTED, formattedJson);
}

@Test
public void should_sort_and_indent_properties() throws Exception {
    // Given
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper = objectMapper
            .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    // When
    String formattedJson = tryingToFormatJson(objectMapper, INDENTED_UNSORTED);

    // Then
    assertEquals(INDENTED_SORTED, formattedJson);
}

//
// Utils
//

private String tryingToFormatJson(ObjectMapper objectMapper, String unformattedJson)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode unsortedTree = objectMapper.readTree(unformattedJson);
    Object treeToValue = objectMapper.treeToValue(unsortedTree, Object.class);
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(treeToValue);
}

}
```

- How could I sort my JSON with Jackson?
- Do you have any solution for implementing my method `tryingToFormatJson`?
- Is Jackson the right tool I want for doing this?

Comment: Well this is what I would call a bad test. First of all these hard-coded line endings and then the fact that you test Jackson and not your code. There is no need for you to test Jackson.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I dont want to test Jackson,an hard-coded endins are here for clarify my needs.
I want a `tryingToFormatJson` method to use in my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `objectMapper.treeToValue(unsortedTree, Object.class)`, the `Object`'s type is a subclass of `Map` - just put a `System.out.println(treeToValue.getClass())` to check.

And according to [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY), `SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY` doesn't sort map keys:

> Feature that defines default property serialization order used for POJO fields (**note: does not apply to Map serialization!**)

---

If you want to sort the fields, you have to create a custom class for you structure, like this:

```
public class Tree {
    private Map<String, Child> firstChild;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Child {
    private String alphaItem;

    private String otherProperty;

    private String someOtherProperty;

    private String alphaType;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And change the `treeToValue` call to:

```
Tree treeToValue = objectMapper.treeToValue(unsortedTree, Tree.class);
```

With this, the fields will be sorted and the test will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Its worked fine.
I also found an other way : the use of `org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert`.


Il looks like : 
`JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJSON, actualJSON, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT)`


Instead of 
`assertEquals(expectedJSON,  tryingToFormatJson(objectMapper, actualJSON));`