# Print JSON with ordered properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON with objects in specific order:

```
{
  "Aaa": {
    "Langs": {
      "Val": [
        "Test"
      ],
      "Pro": [
        "Test2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Bbb": {
    "Langs": {
      "Val": [
        "Test"
      ],
      "Pro": [
        "Test2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Ddd": {
    "Langs": {
      "Val": [
        "Test"
      ],
      "Pro": [
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

And I would like to add new object `Ccc` between `Bbb` and `Ddd`. I tried to configure object mapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        .configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)
        .configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
```

and then print with this code, but `Ccc` ends at the end of file.

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
prettyPrinter.indentArraysWith(DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE);

//Write whole JSON in FILE
String finalJson = mapper.writer(prettyPrinter).writeValueAsString(rootFlores);
finalJson = finalJson.replaceAll("\\[ ]", "[" + System.lineSeparator() + "      ]");
finalJson = finalJson.replaceAll("/", "\\\\/");

Files.write(Paths.get("DictionaryFlores_new.json"), Collections.singleton(finalJson));
```

Is here a way how to print JSON ordered?

Comment: Just a tip: If you are doing this for human searchability and readability, than more power to you, but if you are doing this for some other piece of code that requires it to be in a specific order than that is a bug in that software. The order of properties in JSON should not matter. If you need ordering than you need to add a sub-property that is used for ordering or use an array instead of an object.

Comment: Which version of jackson are you using?

Comment: I know that order should not be important, but the software on other side is blackbox and for now I can change it and have to serve ordered JSON. I'm using version 2.9.6

Comment: I understand, but you should let the maintainers of the blackbox software know that it is a bug.

Comment: It is more than the order "should not be important" but the standard of the JSON syntax is clear about that, object properties are not ordered and are not maintaining there position, only arrays maintain the order of the value. So the parse/formatting of a JSON can modify the representation. If you are using an API that doesn't understand that, then this should be your main concern.

Comment: @AxelH I don't want to argue about this. I would like to resolve my problem :-)

Comment: But that's my point, you don't have a problem ... you are creating a well format JSON no matter where is `Ccc` compared to `Bbb` and `Ddd`. Blackbox developer have a problem ! Right now, you are facing the problem because you need to add a property, but if tomorrow you simply update the JSON API and the logic to stringify the JSON change and now the properties are in the following order `Ddd, Aaa, Ccc, Bbb`, that would be the same thing. 
There are "solution", but none would be nice to see. (I will try to implement one when I can)

Comment: @AxelH That's just not how it works in the real world. You have to work with what you have. Think about all the questions regarding cross-browser support when IE didn't implement some standard. Imagine if everyone answered with "Just don't support IE"

Comment: @Novaterata in real world you start by testing a solution before you start using it in production ;) you can't compare this with a tool that the users are using around the world... but OK let's assume this "small problem" was not notice before, work-around are based on specific case. Here this is already assuming that OPs can build a JSON with "80000 keys" without any problem but with this specific one ... it fails ...

Answer (score 1):

[Jackson deserialization/serialization does not sort properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928568/jackson-deserialization-serialization-does-not-sort-properties)

According to this answer, the Jackson SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY only applies to POJO properties, not Maps. In JSON there is no difference between a Map and an Object, so you need to set the order in the Map first by using a LinkedHashMap or TreeMap

Comment: So if my JSON have arround 80000 keys, I should create custom class with 80000 properties?

Comment: @Sk1X1 No, you can use a LinkedHashMap or TreeMap as I said

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the keys of an object are unordered.  I guess some libraries *could* offer an option to control the order of the keys when stringifying, but I wouldn't count on it.

When you need a certain order in json, you need to use an array.  Of course, then you'd have to move the keys to a property in the child objects, and then the resulting array could only be indexed by number (not by the key).  So then you might have to do additional processing to covert the data structure in the JSON to the data structure you really want to process.

Comment: That's true, but OP is talking about Jackson which does allow alphabetical sorting

Comment: @Novaterata : And yet I stand by the statement I made above: "some libraries could offer an option to control the order ... but I wouldn't count on it".  To be clear, I'm saying I wouldn't count on such options, because it suggests I'm doing something contrary to spec that may cause problems down the line

Answer (score 0):

Since you seems ready to use regex to update a JSON, I would suggest a "safer" approach. Don't try to create a pattern that would unsure that you don't update a value somewhere.

Iterate you values, on object at the time. Stringify the object and append the String yourself. That way, you are in charge of the object order. Example :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
List<JsonPOJO> list = new ArrayList<>();
//populate the list
for(JsonPOJO pojo : list){
    sb.append(pojo.stringify()).append(","); 
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); //remove the last commma
sb.append("}");
```

Here, you are only managing the comma between each JSON object, not create the "complex" part about the JSON. And you are in full control of the order of the value in the String representation, it will only depend on the way you populate the `List`.

Note: sorry for the "draft" code, I don't really have access to my system here so just write this snippet to give you a basic idea on how to "manage" a JSON without having to recreating an API completely.

Note2: I would note suggest this unless this looks really necessary. As you mention in a comment, you are have only the problem with one key where you already have a JSON with 80000 keys, so I guess this is a "bad luck" scenario asking for last resort solution ;)